# "Mom was never one to keep money in her house." vs "She did not used to keep money in her house."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

**"Mom was never one to keep money in her house."**

**"She did not used to keep money in her house."**

These sentences seem to have the same meaning. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

"Did not used to" is not a correct construction (ever).  So the second sentence is incorrect.

You might say "She used to keep no money...", or "She never used to keep..."

The first sentence is an idiomatic expression. "never one to (do something)". But it speaks about your mother's characteristics rather than her habits. It is about *her* not *what she did*.